# {"Input string was not in a correct format."}

Tags: c#, split, switch-statement, case, calculator

I cannot figure out wh i am getting error

"{"Input string was not in a correct format."}"

When I type for example 5+5 into my Sum Textbox and click equals which should then display my answer in my answer textbox, however when I type 5+5 I get the error show above and I cant seem to fix it.

Here is my addition button code

```
    private void Addition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbl_FirstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(Sum.Text); //Operation Works, need to get rid of the 0
        Sum.AppendText(" + ");
```

Here is my equal button code

```
    private void equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] hold = Sum.Text.Split(' ');//
        switch (hold[1])//holds the first number

        {
            case "+":
                Result.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(Sum.Text) + hold[0].ToString() + hold[2].ToString());   
                break;
```

My second problem

Ok so when i try put in 3 + 3 + 3 i get the error
"{"Input string was not in a correct format."}"

here is my addition code

```
     private void Addition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbl_FirstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(Sum.Text); 
        Sum.AppendText(" + ");

    }
```

screenshot of error - https://gyazo.com/9689d4f5055d7cc9211e1c2822b1d6f3

Comment: Convert.ToDouble(Sum.Text) will fail in equals_Click because it has the value "5 + 5" which I am afraid to ask if you expect to be converted to double 10? Well, it won't.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I think that's just a mistake; on the basis that they're adding the two parts of the binary op separately anyway

Answer (score 0):

There are mistakes ...

```
private void equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] hold = Sum.Text.Split(' ');
    switch (hold[1]) // holds the DELIMTER
    {
        case "+":
            Result.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(Sum.Text) + hold[0].ToString() + hold[2].ToString());   
            // THATS WRONG!                                 ^ this would take "5 + 5" and you CANNOT convert this.
            // here you would Need: 
            Result.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(hold[0]) + Convert.ToDouble(hold[2])).ToString();

            break;
```

Comment: Thank you, that is now working, the only issue i have now is if i want to add 3+3+3 doing 3 + 3 works fine but when i click + again i get an error

Comment: do you have different forumlas ( 2 or n elements?) what error? Show complete code.

Comment: As you see in the Result.Text assignment: YOU CANT CONVERT a string like 3 + 3 to da double value -> but thats exactly what you do when clicking on "+"